# I have a traditional IRA. Can I rollover my 401k into that account or do I need to make a new rollover-traditional-ira?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, rollover

Basically that.  I have a traditional IRA and have been contributing 5500 a year.  I need to rollover a couple 401ks from previous jobs, can I move them to the same account?  Or do I need to open a new account, specifically for my rollovers?

Comment: @blacksmith37 - please read https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/the-intent-and-purpose-of-comments (I will remove this comment in a day or two)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on the IRA custodian.

Once upon a time, Rollover IRAs were kept distinct from Traditional IRAs because the money in the Rollover IRA was eligible to be rolled over once again *into* a current employer-sponsored plan (such as a 401(k) or 403(b) account) as long as one did not make IRA *contributions* to the Rollover account - if one tried to do so, the custodian would send dire warnings that such a *commingling* of funds would destroy forever the eligibility of rolling over any of that account money into another 401(k).  This distinction has mostly disappeared with changes in tax laws but some IRA custodians still adhere to it.  So, ask your current IRA custodian about it.

In fact, it is best to start doing the rollover by telling your IRA custodian that you have some money in a 401(k) that you wish to rollover into a IRA and tell *them* to go get the money.  If you approach the 401(k) administrator first, you will get a lot of run-around as to why this is not a good idea and be asked to jump through all sorts of hoops -- they don't want to see money going out the door!  On the other hand, IRA custodians are eager to get their hands on more money to manage and make it easy to do a 401(k) rollover.

Go to the IRA custodian's website (or call their toll-free number) and they will be happy to help you navigate the rollover process and take care of all the details without much hassle for you.